# How to forbid calling .env configuration file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have uploaded all Laravel files to hosting. Now I can call .env file directly by URL and get configuration setting.

How can I hide this and forbid?

Comment: Your `.env` file should be ideally in a directory not accessible to the public, usually, the `app` directory is one directory above `public`. However, you should be able to restrict access to this file using `.htaccess`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.env` file should be ideally in a directory not accessible to the public, usually, it's in the directory above `public`.

However, you should be able to restrict access to this file using `.htaccess`. I *think* you can do something like this to achieve it (Not tested it):

```
<Files ".env">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```